# PHP can't get AJAX data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to send variable data to my database.php file
but php can't get it

the Validate() method works when i click on my submit button which has an onlick event.

here's my Validate() function

```
function Validate()
        {
            var frm=jQuery('#AdminForm');
            var valid="false";

             jQuery.ajax({  
                type: frm.attr('method'),           
                url: frm.attr('action'),                
                data: 'var='+valid,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert("error: "+thrownError);
                }
            });

        }
```

here's my php file

```
<?php
   echo $_POST["var"];
?>
```

but php leads to an error which says: **undefined index var**

please help me to fix this.

Comment: Your form method is POST ?

Comment: You can access `var` with `$_GET['var']` (the default is get)

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` it will take both get or post request.

Comment: [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Try `data: {'var':valid},`

Comment: i'm using $_REQUEST but it leads to the same error:
My form method is post

Comment: Try what mcklayin suggested.

Comment: could you please `var_dump($_REQUEST)` on your php script and paste it here?

Comment: var_dump returns NULL:
now i'm using data: {'var':valid},

Comment: var valid="false"; it will not send any data because you set it false

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST) returned this
array(10) { ["question"]=> string(0) "" ["AnswersCount"]=> string(1) "2" ["answer1"]=> string(0) "" ["answer2"]=> string(0) "" ["bg_color"]=> string(6) "FFFFFF" ["border_color"]=> string(6) "FFFFFF" ["answer_color"]=> string(6) "FFFFFF" ["Question_color"]=> string(6) "FFFFFF" ["Text_Font"]=> string(24) "Abadi MT Condensed Light" ["fontSize"]=> string(2) "14" }

Comment: Is the button actually a submit button or merely a button? WIthout preventing the default action of the submit button the form will POST as it is supposed to but bypassing ajax.

Answer (score 0):

According to you you are using "post" method for your form, but you call Validate function inside onclick of "submit" button, it's better to change the type of the button to "button" or to stop the default behavior of the form by adding onsubmit="return false;"

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting your form via `GET` which is default for jQuery ajax, so you will need to check for

```
$_GET['var']
```

Other way would be to change your ajax call to

```
jQuery.ajax({  
                type: frm.attr('method'),     // make sure this is post      
                url: frm.attr('action'),                
                data: {
                    var : valid
                }
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert("error: "+thrownError);
                }
            });
```